# How to get magento header in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, magento

I am having word press installed in side a sub directory of magento like

```
---Magento
   ----wp
         --Blog  (This is word press directory)
```

In word press we have header.php in theme folder.There I am trying to access the magento header block.

I am able to get this following way(Below code is written in head section of **header.php** of wordpress)

```
Mage::getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_head')->toHtml();
```

When I echo this I am able to get the magento header.But the css and js of magento application are not rendered as well the word press application is halting after rendering the content of magento. i.e  nothing comes after header.

Please suggest me idea how can I get the css and js of magento application and the wordpress content properly?

Answer (score 0):

The dirty way is to link Magento JS and CSS in your header.php file. like

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php getSkinUrl('jsfolder/js.js') ?>"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php getSkinUrl('cssfolder/style.css') ?>">
```

There's actually a tweak in page.xml file but I wonder how, or why not to play it yourself?